# Possible to execute a command inside minikube without SSH into it and then executing command

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Just curious if it is possible to execute a command inside `minikube` without doing `minikube ssh` and then executing the command.

Something like:

`minikube ssh exec -it <command>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the minikube documentation (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/commands/ssh/) there is no such option.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, it is possible. Just run:

```
minikube ssh '<command>'
```

For example:

```
minikube ssh 'ls -la'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to execute a command directly to the minikube node:

```
ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip) <command>
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: It fails like `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused` any suggestions?